# SQL date variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am busy creating a table in SQL on SQL server 2012, i would like to know how i would create a date variable that stores the date when creating the table.

Any advice on how to do this or go about doing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give more details ? you want to store the date on which the table has been created into variable ?

Comment: we cant come to sauth africa for this. plz mention detsils over here

Comment: Sorry for clarity, i want to store a date value in this variable. I will be pulling the system date into this variable.

Comment: while creating a table ,you can have `default values` for a column `yourDateColumn Datetime DEFAULT GETDATE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GETDATE ( )` .

Following is the link for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

```
select colname where datecol=GETDATE ()
```

This query migh help you.

Comment: Not 100% what im looking for but it definatly helped me. Here is the exact answer to my solution that i made: create table tablename(sysdate Datetime DEFAULT GETDATE())

Comment: okey, means GETDATE() helped you. fine.. Do one thing, edit some part in your question :i want to store a date value in this variable. I will be pulling the system date into this variable